# KOhana.. simple function need help

Tags: php, kohana

I m new to kohana..
Guyz plz point out the mistakes in the following code.. i m unable to run it.. Its a simple connection to database.. can i compare the query result and the psot item as i have done so.. plz correct..

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
/**
* Default Kohana controller.
*/
class index_Controller extends Controller {
public function index()
{
$db = new Database();
$index = new View('Index')
$db->connect();
name = $post['name'];
password = $post['password'];
$result = $db->query('name');
foreach($result as $row)
{
  if($row->Password === password)
  {
    echo "login Successful" ;
   }

        }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
/**
* Default Kohana controller.
*/
class index_Controller extends Controller {
public function index()
{
$db = new Database();
$index = new View('Index')
$db->connect();
name = $post['name'];
password = $post['password'];
$result = $db->query('name');
foreach($result as $row)
{
  if($row->Password === password)
  {
    echo "login Successful" ;
   }

  }
}
 
}
?>

Comment: What Kohana version is it? 2.3.4?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Kohana has got a build in [Auth](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Auth) system, recommend using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
   $db = new Database();
   $index = new View('Index'); // unused var?
   //$db->connect();
   $name = Arr::get($_POST, 'name');
   $password = Arr::get($_POST, 'password');
   if ( ! $name OR !$password)
   {
      die('name and password required!');
   }
   $user = $db->select('*')   // use Query Builder!
           ->from('users')
           ->where('username', $name)
           ->get();
   if ( empty($user))
   {
      die('user '.$user.' not found!');
   }
   $user = current($user);
   if ($user['password'] == $password)
   {
       // correct password
   }
   else
   {
       die('wrong username/password combination!');
   }

}
```

Its for Kohana v2.3.4 (3.x has another controllers and methods name convention)

Answer (score 0):

Line:

`$index = new View('Index')`

missing ";" at the end. Write:

`$index = new View('Index');`

Lines:

```
name = $post['name'];
password = $post['password'];
```

Missing `$` before variable names. `$post` should be `$_POST` or better, use Kohana `Arr::get()` (see biakaveron's answer).

Advice:

Instead of writing `defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');` at the top of each script file, configure Apache to hide those files from Apache's "scope", or add a **.htaccess** to prevent direct access to some directories.